# Doughnutchart achartengine legend not showing

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to use legend (and not labels) with a Doughnut chart using achartengine library in Android.  The problem is that the legend does not show.  I am making the right function calls to show legend and set its text size.  With similar function calls, I am able to get a legend in Pie chart but not on Doughnut chart.

```
MultipleCategorySeries category1series = new MultipleCategorySeries("Doughnut Chart");
category1series.add(slice_name, slice_value);

DefaultRenderer pieChartRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
pieChartRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
pieChartRenderer.setLegendTextSize(targetTextSize);
pieChartRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your label color, add :

`pieChartRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: I have also set the labels color and the labels are showing.  But as I mentioned, I DO NOT want the labels. I want the legend.